# Intel Fortran vectorisation: vector loop cost higher than scalar

Tags: fortran, vectorization, simd, intel-fortran

I'm testing and optimising a legacy code with Intel Fortran 15, and I have this simple loop:

```
do ir=1,N(lev)
  G1(lev)%D(ir) = 0.d0
  G2(lev)%D(ir) = 0.d0
enddo
```

where `lev` is equal to some integer.

Structures and indexes are quite complex for the compiler, but it can succeed in the task, as I can see on other lines.
Now, on the above loop, I get this from the compilation report:

```
LOOP BEGIN at MLFMATranslationProd.f90(38,2)
  remark #15399: vectorization support: unroll factor set to 4
  remark #15300: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
  remark #15462: unmasked indexed (or gather) loads: 2
  remark #15475: --- begin vector loop cost summary ---
  remark #15476: scalar loop cost: 12
  remark #15477: vector loop cost: 20.000
  remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 2.340
  remark #15479: lightweight vector operations: 5
  remark #15481: heavy-overhead vector operations: 1
  remark #15488: --- end vector loop cost summary ---
LOOP END
```

My question is: how is it that the **vector loop cost** is higher than the scalar one? What can I do to go towards the `estimated potential speedup`?

Comment: Can you confirm you really meant intel-fortran by your intel tag? Which compiler version you use and which options you use? Which CPU you have?

Comment: I can't see your problem, the compiler sees a potential speedup and vectorized the code. Where do you see any problem? Vector operations carry indeed some cost, but in this case the cost is not too high and the compiler did the vectorization.

Comment: Yes, I meant intel fortran, using ifort 15. As far as I understand, the _loop cost_ is the number of clock cycle taken to perform an instruction, so I would expect a minor vector loop cost if an estimated potential speedup > 1 is evaluated by the compiler. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *loop cost* is an estimate of the duration of one loop iteration and it takes somewhat longer in the vectorized case, but you can process more array items in one vectorized iteration.

In your case the speedup is roughly 12 / 20 * 4 = 2.4 because you can process 4 double precision array elements in one iteration (probably the AVX instructions).

Comment: The formula (12 / 20 * 4 = 2.4) is correct, but explanation is not exactly right. Unroll factor value is completely unrelated to 2.4 x gain estimate in given case. "4" in given formula - is likely Vector Length value. So given loop was unrolled by factor of 4, and AFTER that it was vectorized with Vector Length of 4. Gain Estimate may possibly not account unrolling at all, but it accounted Vector Length.

Comment: @zam Yes, of course I mean the vector length. But it is unrolled so that the unrolled iterations can be put in one vector instruction, therefore they are connected. Notice I write "...because you can process 4 double...", that obviously means the vector length.

Comment: Unroll factor will not influence 2.34 value, at least in normal case. If you disable unroll, you will normally get very similar estimate. Even if unroll was accounted in this estimate, it was not accounted as multiplier of 4.  It was my point. So unroll factor is unrelated to original question.

Comment: To further clarify: by unrolling by 4 and using Vector Length of 4, you normally put 16 scalar iterations into the final single optimized loop iteration. But while it's 16 original iterations corresponding to final one, the real speed-up per instruction is around 4, because you process only 4 values in parallel on VPU register.

Comment: @zam I deleted the sentence but I believe you are wrong. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fdiag15144 The loop is first unrolled and then vectorized. There are only 4 elements per iteration (in one vector instructions' sequence).

Comment: I will try to double-check if the article referenced by you has actually supposed to say what it says. Regardless of it, normally unrolling and vectorization are orthogonal dimensions, and both can simulteneously apply.

Comment: Vladimir, I double-checked. For Intel Compiler version 16 opt-reports, the behavior is like I desribed (unroll factor and vector length are reported independently). For Intel Compiler 15 opt-reports - the behavior is different, because it may happen that reported unroll factor sometimes "accounts" vector length indirectly (which is a little bit confusing, but this how it works for given article on web). So: unrolling and vectorization are completely orthogonal, however reporting unroll factor and vector length are somewhat confusing in opt-report for 15.x, although it's "fixed" in 16.x

Comment: Yes they are orthogonal, but you can't vectorize a loop without first unrolling it (conceptually). You simply have to lower the number of loop iterations, there is no other way. And 16 is still to new for me, my code didn't work in early 15 because of Intel's regressions and ARCHER supercomputer still uses 14 as the default.

Comment: Not really: you can vectorize loop without unrolling. Big fraction of efficiently vectorized loops are not unrolled at all (i have kinda statistics on some specs). Unrolling sometimes prevents loops from being efficiently vectorized. I don't argue in favor of Compiler 14.x vs. 15.x vs. 16.x etc. I just wanted to explain what's going on, why IDZ article is kinda confusing and what is a difference between opt-report versions. Hope it was helpful, although I see that it sounds surprising and doubtful to you. Again, try #pragma nounroll and you will see plenty of still vectorized loops:-)

Comment: And concept of "packed" (i.e. parallel) iterations is kind of very, very different from concept of "unrolled" (i.e. sequential) iterations grouping

Comment: You don't get what I say. The vectorization IS a form of unrolling by itself, you first unroll the loop by the factor equal to the vector length and then stuff everything into the vector instruction. I do not care about any further unrolling AT ALL here. So in the end it is not unrolled, but it was before you changed the operations to vector ones. But I find this discussion quite pointless.

Comment: See my very last comment. Even conceptually they are very very different. This is something by analogy with serialization vs. parallelization.

Comment: There is no point discussing this, it is just arguing about exact meaning of some stupid words.