# fortran limits of vectorization

Tags: fortran, vectorization

I have written a function that returns a vector A equal to the product of a sparse matrix Sparse by another vector F.  The non-zero values of the matrix are in Sparse(nnz), rowind(nnz) and colind(nnz) each contain the row and column of each particular value of Sparse.  It was relatively simple to vectorize the (now commented) inner loop by the two lines beneath do kx....  I cannot see how to vectorize the outer loop, since pos has different size for different kx.

The question is : can the outer loop (do kx=1,nxy) be vectorized, and if yes how?

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Vladimir F correctly surmises that I come from the Python/Octave world.  I have moved (back) to fortran to get more performance out of my hardware, as the PDE I solve become larger.  As of a half hour ago, vectorization meant to get rid of do loops, something that fortran seems very good at:  the time savings involved in replacing the "inner loop" (do ky=1,size(pos)..) by the two lines above is astonishing.  I look at the info given by gfortran (really gcc?) when -fopt-info is invoked and see loop modification is often used.  I will immediately go and read about SIMD and array notation. Please,please if there are good sources on this topic please let me know.

In reply to Holz, there are myriad ways to store sparse matrices, usually resulting in lowering the rank of the operator by 1:  The example I cooked up involves forcing and solution vectors that are evaluated at each position in some field,and therefore have rank 1.  The operator that relates then (S, as in A= S . F)  is two dimensional BUT sparse.  It is stored in such a way that only nonzero values are kept.  If there are nnz non-zero values in S, then Sp, the sparse equivalent to S, is Sp(1:nnz).  If pos represents the location within that sequence of some number Sp(pos), then the column and row position in the original matrix S is given by colind(pos) and rowind(pos).

With that background, I might enlarge the question to:  What is the very best (measured by execution time) that can be done to accomplish the multiplication?

```
pure function SparseMul(Sparse,F) result(A)
  implicit none
  integer (kind=4),allocatable :: pos(:)
  integer (kind=4) :: kx,ky   ! gp counters
  real (kind=8),intent(in) :: Sparse(:),F(:)
  real (kind=8),allocatable :: A(:)
  allocate(A(nxy))
  do kx=1,nxy                 !for each row
    pos=pack([(ky,ky=1,nnz)],rowind==kx)
    A(kx)=sum(Sparse(pos)*F(colind(pos)))
!!$       A(kx)=0
!!$       do ky=1,size(pos)
!!$          A(kx)=A(kx)+Sparse(pos(ky))*F(colind(pos(ky)))
!!$       end do
  end do
end function SparseMul
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *vectorize*? Array notation or SIMD intrinsics? I am assuming the former, but please confirm. In relation to Fortran vectorization usually means the latter.

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is to parallelize outer, vectorize inner for SIMD. SIMD works better with packed data for locality of reference. You might be able to turn the outer loop into a `for all` or add OMP directives. As you are taking a sum, Holmz’s suggestion of a reduce operation is a good one.

Comment: From the example I am quite convinced that the OP means something else under [tag:vectorization] than what you and @Holmz in his answer (see my first comment). See also the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075566/vectorized-array-comparison-in-fortran  This notion as *vectorization* as the array notation is widely used in Python.

Comment: @Vladimir F : My early reading indicates that SIMD is synonym for using OpenMP constructs??

Comment: @ClintonWinant No, not at all. Most OpenMP is about parallel threads, not about SIMD. SIMD is using of the CPU SIMD instructions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD It does not matter if the compiler does that automatically, or after your suggestion (in OpenMP or elsewhere). Using of SIMD is also called *vectorization* (like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644203/how-to-determine-what-gfortran-is-vectorizing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561972/intel-fortran-vectorisation-vector-loop-cost-higher-than-scalar and other similar questions)

Comment: @Franz awesome, I am marking this answered until I've had time to work my way through all your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question "as is", i.e.:

- we do not want to change the matrix storage format
- we do not want to use an external library to perform the task

Otherwise, I think that using an external library should
be the best way to approach the problem, e.g.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520797.

It is not easy to predict the "best" Fortran way to write the 
multiplication. It depends on several factors (compiler, architecture,
matrix size,...). I think that the best strategy is to propose 
some (reasonable) attempts and test them in a realistic configuration.

If I correctly understand the matrix storage format, my attempts -- including those reported in the question -- are provided 
below:

1. save non-zero positions using pack

   ```
   do kx=1,nxy
      pos=pack([(ky,ky=1,nnz)],rowind==kx)
      A(kx)=0
      do ky=1,size(pos)
         A(kx)=A(kx)+Sparse(pos(ky))*F(colind(pos(ky)))
      end do
   end do
   ```
2. as the previous one but using Fortran array syntax

   ```
   do kx=1,nxy
      pos=pack([(ky,ky=1,nnz)],rowind==kx)
      A(kx)=sum(Sparse(pos)*F(colind(pos)))
   end do
   ```
3. use a conditional to determine the components to be used

   ```
   do kx=1,nxy
      A(kx)=0
      do ky=1,nnz
         if(rowind(ky)==kx) A(kx)=A(kx)+Sparse(ky)*F(colind(ky))
      end do
   end do
   ```
4. as the previous one but interchanging loops

   ```
   A(:)=0
   do ky=1,nnz
      do kx=1,nxy
        if(rowind(ky)==kx) A(kx)=A(kx)+Sparse(ky)*F(colind(ky))
      end do
   end do
   ```
5. use the intrisic `sum` with the mask argument

   ```
   do kx=1,nxy    
      A(kx)=sum(Sparse*F(colind), mask=(rowind==kx))
   enddo
   ```
6. as the previous one but using an implied do-loop

   ```
   A =[(sum(Sparse*F(colind), mask=(rowind==kx)), kx=1,nxy)]
   ```

These are the results using a 1000x1000 matrix with
33% non-zero values.  The machine is an Intel Xeon
and my tests were performed using Intel v17 and GNU 6.1 compiler 
using no optimization, high optimization but
without vectorization, and high optimization.

```
          V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
-O0
ifort    4.28 4.26 0.97 0.91 1.33 2.70
gfortran 2.10 2.10 1.10 1.05 0.30 0.61

-O3 -no-vec
ifort    0.94 0.91 0.23 0.22 0.23 0.52
gfortran 1.73 1.80 0.16 0.15 0.16 0.32

-O3
ifort    0.59 0.56 0.23 0.23 0.30 0.60
gfortran 1.52 1.50 0.16 0.15 0.16 0.32
```

A few short comments on the results:

- Versions 3-4-5 are usually the fastest ones
- The role of compiler optimizations is crucial for any version
- The vectorization seems to play an important role only for 
  the non-optimal versions
- Version 4 is the best for both compilers
- gfortran V4 is the *"best"* version
- Elegance does not always mean good performance (V6 is not very good)
- Additional comments can be done analyzing the reports of the 
  compiler optimizations.

If we have a multi-core machine, we can try to use
all the cores. This implies dealing with the code parallelization, which
is a wide issue, but just to give some hints let us test
two possible OpenMP parallelizations. We work on the
serial fastest version (even though there is no guarantee it
is also the best version to be parallelized).

OpenMP 1.

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp workshare
    A(:)=0
!$omp end workshare
!$omp do 
    do ky=1,nnz
      do kx=1,nxy                 !for each row
        if(rowind(ky)==kx) A(kx)=A(kx)+Sparse(ky)*F(colind(ky))
      end do
    end do
!$omp end do 
!$omp end parallel
</pre>
```

OpenMP 2. add firstprivate to read-only vectors to improve memory access

```
!$omp parallel firstprivate(Sparse, colind, rowind)
    ...
!$omp end parallel
```

These are the results for up to 16 threads on 16 cores:

```
#threads   1     2     4     8    16
OpenMP v1
ifort    0.22  0.14 0.088 0.050 0.027
gfortran 0.155 0.11 0.064 0.035 0.020
OpenMP v2
ifort    0.24  0.12 0.065 0.042 0.029
gfortran 0.157 0.11 0.052 0.036 0.029
```

The scalability (around 8 at 16 threads) is reasonable considering 
that it is a memory-bound computation. The firstprivate optimization
has advantages only for a small number of threads. gfortran using 
16 threads is the *"best"* OpenMP solution.

Comment: I can duplicate your results w/o OMP, but when I try with OMP I get no change with number of threads, or a slight increase.  To compile I use gfortran -fopenmp -O3  before running in do export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4.  Do I need to add anything to the main program (this is my 1st use of OpenMP)?  I am on ubuntu 16.04 with corei7-2600 (4cores + HT)

Comment: How do you evaluate the timings? It is easier if you use a wall-time function, e.g. date_and_time, just before and after the parallel region instead of cpu timings (e.g., cpu_time) which return the sum of thread times. For fine measurements there is also the omp_get_wtime function.

Comment: cpu_time was indeed the problem.   Now I reproduce evrything.  Thanks for taking the time to make such a rich response.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time seeing where COLIND is and what it is doing... And also KX and KY. For the inner loop you want that vectorized, and that seems easiest for me using OpenMP SIMD REDUCTION. I am specifically looking here:

```
!!$       A(kx)=0
!!$       do ky=1,size(pos)
!!$          A(kx)=A(kx)+Sparse(pos(ky))*F(colind(pos(ky)))
!!$       end do
```

If you have to gather (PACK) then it may not help much. If there are more than 7/8 of zeros in F then F is likely better to PACK. Otherwise it may be better to vector multiply everything (including the zero-sums).

The main rule is that the data needs to be contiguous, so you cannot vectorize across the second dimension... If feels like Sparse and F are rank=2, but they are shown as being RANK=1. That works fine for going through as a vector, even if they are really a rank=2 array. UNION/MAP can also be used to implement a 2D array as also being a 1D vector.

Are Sparse and F really rank=1? and what are nax, nay, nxy and colind used for? And many of those are not defined (e.g. nay , nnz and colind )

Comment: Please do not advertise UNION/MAP, it is not part of any Fortran. The good old standard EQUIVALENCE is often fine for mapping conforming arrays of different ranks (non-allocatable).

Comment: UNION/MAP is actually going into gcc/gfortran, and it has been in many fortran compilers. But I see your point, and I will study up on EQUIVALENCE to see how that goes, and start removing the historical.